# How to do hooks before Mongodb query execution?

Tags: mongodb

I want to change field name before executing query into mongodb.

Example:

```
db.mycol.find({key1:value1, key2:value2}).pretty()
```

should be changed to as below

```
db.mycol.find({key12:value1, key20:value2}).pretty()
```

Is there any hook system i can change dynamically?

Comment: I think you should handle that in your application side itself

Comment: I was thinking same, but identifying fields and replacing on complex queries is difficult.  if its only find query i can easily identify the fields. otherwise its difficult.